# Best way to assign property using enum c#

Tags: c#, enums

How can I effective extend enum to have more than 2 options.
I am reading events from a file, line-by-line.
I have a constructor

```
public enum EventType
{ A,D }

public class Event
{
    public EventType Type { get; set; }

}
```

I assigned Type property like this:

```
 Type = tokens[2].Equals("A") ? EventType.A : EventType.D,
```

where `token[2]` is the string that holds values like "A".

This works fine when there are only `A` and `D`, but I want to have 2 more types; say `R` and `C`. When I add them to enum field, how can I get the type? The above is giving compilation errors as if using Type as a variable.

I appreciate your immediate help!
Thanks

Comment: You could have more chance if you ask **politely** someone to help you. Immediately is not a nice word here

Comment: you are right @Steve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really only three sensible ways to go about this:

### Enum.TryParse

If the tokens will always correspond *exactly* to your enum members, you can use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse.aspx):

```
EventType type;
if (Enum.TryParse(tokens[2], out type)) {
    Type = type;
}
else { /* token does not exist as an enum member */ }
```

This approach is the simplest, but it's probably slower than the next one and it also has another drawback: the author of the code that provides `tokens[2]` and the author of the enum must always keep their code in sync.

### Use a dictionary

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, EventType>
{
    { "A", EventType.A },
    { "D", EventType.D },
    // more items here
}

Type = dict[tokens[2]]; // no error checking, please add some
```

This requires some setup, but it's probably the fastest and it also allows accounting for changes in the input strings and/or enum values.

### Use an attribute

Alternatively, you can annotate your enum members with a custom attribute and write a helper method that uses reflection to find the correct member based on the value of this attribute. This solution has its uses but it's the least likely candidate; most of the time you should prefer one of the two alternatives.

Comment: With Dictionary, don't forget to add a check if the element exists. Else you will get an exception.

Comment: Beware of Framework version.. `Enum.TryParse` was added in .NET 4.0.

Comment: They are different words, but I put them as such in the dict field. It seems to work now. This version is clearer than switch; but switched worked as well.

Comment: Need to consider this TryParse though. for the time being, this is ok since there are only those 4 possible elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Enum.Parse` to parse a string. For error handling you may use `Enum.GetNames(typeof(EventType))` and iterate over the returned string array, which contains all possible names of the enum.

```
var type = (EventType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EventType), tokens[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can want to use [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse) to get the matching value:

```
Type = Enum.Parse(typeof(EventType), tokens[2])
```

If `tokens[2]` is not defined in `EventType`, `Enum.Parse` throws an exception, so you can use [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined) to check if there is an enum value for the string:

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EventType), tokens[2])
```

Comment: Nice, didnt know about `Enum.IsDefined` as a < .NET 4.0 fallback for `Enum.TryParse`. Thanks. :)

Answer (score -2):

```
EventType et;
switch(tokens[2]) 
{
   case "A":
      et=EventType.A;
      break;
   case "B":
      et=EventType.B;
      break;
   case "C":
      et=EventType.C;
      break;
}
return et;
```

Comment: This does not really scale well. Thanks though!